# Is it possible to create a Photoimage object from graph using pydot?

Tags: python, tkinter, graphviz, pydot

In my program I want to use pydot to be able to display image of a graph. I found a solution by using `write_png` and then creating Photoimage object using the created file. But I want to know whether it is possible to do this directly without creating a file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `img = tk.PhotoImage(data=graph.create_png())`?

Comment: @acw1668 I tried to use this function but I used wrong keyword argument, not "data" but "file". Now it works, thanks